# primefaces tab on click

Tags: primefaces, tabs, onclick

I have a primefaces tab view like this :

```
<p:tabView id="tabView">  
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">  
        This tab has static content.
    </p:tab>  

    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">  
        this tab has a datatable whose  
    </p:tab>  
</p:tabView>
```

Now, what I want to do is, fire a managedbean method when user clicks on tab2. I can add an actionlistener on tabchange event of tabView but this will fire the method on click of tab1 too. How do I fire a method on click of tab2 only?

Answer (score 17):

Action listener will be called at click of every tab of your tabView.
But you can control your action Listener by conditional blocks like this.
Here is an example:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true">

    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{Bean.onTabChange}" update=":messages" />
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="#{userLbl['notification.headerIncoming']}">
    <p:tab id="tab2" title="#{userLbl['notification.headerOutgoing']}">
</p:tabView>
```

Action Listener:

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {

   if (event.getTab().getId().equals("tab1")) {
       //Your actions for tab1
   } else if((event.getTab().getId().equals("tab2")) {
     //Your actions for tab2
   }
}
```